# Determining the sigma notation for the series: 1 + 2 - 3 + 4 - 5 + 6 - 7 + 8 - 9 . . . . .?

Tags: sequences-and-series

As stated above, the series is:

1 + 2 - 3 + 4 - 5 + 6 - 7 + 8 - 9 + 10 - 11 + 12 - 13 + 14 - 15 . . . ± (n - 1) ∓ n

What would the sigma notation be for this series, starting at 1, ending at n?

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 3):

$$2+\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k}\cdot k$$

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, either.  If the first term is +1, one can just add 2 to this.

Comment: Nah. Meant it to start with the +1.

Comment: @JessicaHope Adjusted.

Comment: Thank you very much, Julien!

Answer (score 0):

i think 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+\lfloor\frac{1}{k}\rfloor}\cdot k$$
works